# Is there scaffold concept in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails-4

As I am familiar with rails, I can simply do:

```
$ script/generate scaffold User name:string email:string
$ rake db:migrate
```

but, as I am newbie in nodejs, how would I start a controller with new/edit/delete/update/create actions inplace with their views? is there something in nodejs like scaffold in rails?

Can someone point me to a good node intro based on rails developer mindset?

Comment: Node.js is a runtime, not a web framework like Rails.  There are dozens of Node.js web frameworks for you to pick from, some of which are very similar to Rails.

Comment: Thanks for info, I found sailsjs, looks like rails, I will check it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), which has app generator templates which kind of do what you want.

Comment: Is it better than sailsjs ?

Comment: Yeoman is just a generator; it generates templates for various frameworks.